# Firefox extension, need advice

Tags: firefox-addon

I've never built a ff extension before and before I start I want some feedback on my idea to make sure its possible.

I want a firefox extension that allows me to supply a url with parameters in GET format, the extension would take the url, parse it, and submit the request as POST rather than GET.

Is this possible? and could someone give me some advice on how to start designing an extension? or point me at a tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

You definitely can!  Parsing the URL's can be done with any javascript library you can find such as [parseUri](http://badassery.blogspot.com/2007/02/parseuri-split-urls-in-javascript.html) or you can do it with the mozilla component [nsIURLParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIURLParser#parseURL%28%29).

After that it is only a matter of actually executing the POST request with a [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).  I think that should be the easy part to do.  The hard part will be getting up to speed with Firefox extension development.  The [Add-on Builder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/tools/builder) can set you with with a minimal Firefox extension as a building block.

Good Luck!

Comment: Good answer. Do you by chance know of an example? I've googled around a bit and the reference material on firefox extensions seems thin and outdated. I already have an extension made, but what I'd like to do is(in JS) take the current windows URL(that's easy) and send it as a POST param to a hardcoded URL. Any advice would be great, thanks.

Comment: @LoveMe  the [XMLHttpRequest Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Creating_a_FormData_object_from_scratch) give an example of sending a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but as the [**Tamper Data**](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/966) plugin is able to manipulate HTTP request, it should be possible.

Have a look at the source code of the plugin to get some ideas.